# What is numerically positive cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm reading some paper recently. I find a notion which I can not find the exact definition. What is the numerically positive cone in the Neron-Severi group?

Comment: It could mean several things. What is the paper you read it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the definitions would be the set of real (1,1)-cohomology classes $\alpha$ such that for any analytic cycle $Y\subset X$ of dimension $\dim Y=d$ one has $\int_Y\alpha^d>0$. A result of Demailly-Paun shows that the Kähler cone is nothing but a connected component of the numerically positive one.

Comment: Now, let $X$ be a non-singular projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$ and $L$ be a line bundle on $X$. The cone is defined by $c_1(L)^2 >0$ and $c_1(L)\cdot H >0$ in the Neron-Severi group. Is this cone and K$\ddot{a}$hler cone coincide? Where H denotes the hyperplane bundle.

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is projective algebraic, then the two coincide (see Demailly).